# Recently added product are not listed in the site search in Umbraco site search

Tags: umbraco, microsoft-commerce-server

I’m working on a web project which uses Umbraco CMS, we are using the site search functionality to find the products on our site it is working fine, when I add new products to the commerce server 2009 R2 it is being listed in the respective category, but these newly added products are not available in the site search. We are using Adobe Search & Promote to index the site, commerce server search technology to search the product. Any clue on this?

Thanks in Advance!
Govind

Comment: Are you using Umbraco XSLTSearch for your search?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is isolate the problem and re-ask the question. Is it Umbraco, Adobe Search & Promote or MS Commerce? Currently your question show's that you yourself do not understand your own project.

Comment: Do you have any further info on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of this discussion, lets say that your Microsoft Commerce Server site name is **'GovinSite*'** and you have a single Microsoft Commerce Server product catalog named **'GovinCatalog'**

Now let me state two assumptions based on your intial question:

Assumption 1: I interpret your statement, *"when I add new products to the commerce server 2009 R2 it is being listed in the respective category*", as decribing the act of you adding products manually using the '**Microsoft Commerce Server Catalog Manager**' thin client tool and then seeing them show up in the interface once you've added them through the thin client interface in Catalog Manager

Assumption 2: I interpret your statement, *"'but these newly added products are not available in the site search** to mean that the newly added products do not show up immediately in the search results on your website which uses Commerce Server Search to return results.

Now, consider that Microsoft Commerce Server 2009 R2 stores all of its products in SQL Server in the **GovinSite_ProductCatalog** database. For each catalog you create, a corresponding set of tables is created in SQL Server. The categories you define and products within those categories are stored in the **GovinCatalog_CatalogProducts** table within that database. When you add a product or category through code, or using the asmx based CatalogWebService or via the Commerce Server Catalog Manager, that product gets added to the **GovinCatalog_CatalogProducts** table. That said, whether or not the product will IMMEDIATELY show up in your live search results will depend on the caching strategy you have implemented for the site. If you are indeed using Microsoft Commerce Server search, depending on the type of search you are executing it is likely using the full text search index. If you have not refreshed either the site cache or the full text search index in Commerce Server, you may experience a situation where you can see the product in Catalog Manager, but it is NOT visible on your site. Refreshing your site cache OR refreshing the full text catalog index will resolve this issue. If it does not fix your problem, then you likely have a problem stemming from the code you are using to search for products using the Commerce Server Catalog API (either 2007 or 2009).

So, since you state you are using Adobe Search & Promote to index the site, I would imagine you are talking about the site content, but not necessarily the site product catalog data. The index used by adobe is likely a completely different index than the one leveraged by Commerce Server Full Text Search. Before you go to far try the following:

1) Create a product in Catalog Manager
2) Try to search for the product on your site
3) Assuming it doesn't show up, go back to Microsoft Commerce Server Catalog Manager and select **Refresh Catalog Full Text Index** from the task menu on the left hand side
4) Try to search for the product again on your site
5) If it still doesn't show up, go back to Microsoft Commerce Server Catalog Manager and select **Refresh Site Cache**
6) Try to search for the product again on your site
7) If it still doesn't show up, it must be an issue with the code that is making search requests to Commerce Server's database either via the Commerce Foundation (2009 API) or the Core Systems Catalog API (2007)

For more information on Microsoft Commerce Server caching, try [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544712%28v=cs.70%29.aspx)

For more information on the Commerce Server 2007 Catalog API searching try [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545468%28v=cs.70%29.aspx)

I could go deeper on this, but I would prefer to let you validate my assumptions and respond before I explore your matter further.